# Uniqueness quantification definition

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

My textbook introduces shorthand for "exists unique" qualifier $\exists !y [P(y)]$, where full version is: $$\exists y[P(y) \land \forall y'[P(y') \Rightarrow y' = y]]$$

What I can't get is why $\Rightarrow$, not $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ used? Saying $\Rightarrow$ means that $P(y')$ could be false, however $y' = y$ or $P(y')$ holds and yet $y' \not = y$. However, as far as I understand, having **unique** $y$ means that this **and only** this $y$ would satisfy statement $P$; hence, whenver statement is true, **it must be** $y$ and vice versa: whenever it is $y$, statement **must be** true.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't have $P(y)\wedge \neg P(y')\wedge (y'=y)$. The proposition, as written, is saying exactly what you said in the second to last sentence.

Comment: Because by axiom for equality: if $P(y)$ and $y=y'$, then $P(y')$ follows.

Comment: So it is indeed possible to define uniqueness like $\exists x \forall y : P(x) \land P(y) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow x = y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the biconditional in the statement

$$\exists y (P(y) \land \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow x=y))$$

because it is already making it explicit that $y$ has property $P$ by the very $P(y)$

But if we are *not* using $P(y)$, then we can use a binconditional to make sure $y$ has property $P$:

$$\exists y \forall x (P(x) \leftrightarrow x=y)$$

As such, throwing the $P(y)$ back in in statements like

$$\exists y (P(y) \land \forall x(P(x) \leftrightarrow x=y))$$

or

$$\exists y \forall x (P(y) \land (P(x) \leftrightarrow x=y))$$

while still correct, is redundant.

In sum: yes, you thought about this absolutely correctly in that we should try to say that 'all and only those things that are identical to $y$ have property $P$' ... it's just that it can be done without a biconditional, and if you use a biconditional, it can be done a little more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

1) $P(y) \land \forall y' \ [P(y') \to y=y']$ --- premise

2) $P(y)$ from 1) by [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination)

3) $y=y'$ --- assumed [a]

4) $P(y')$ --- from 2) and 3) by [Axioms for equality : Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms)

5) $y=y' \to P(y')$ --- from 3) and 4) by [Conditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof), discharging [a]

6) $P(y') \to y=y'$ --- from 1) by Conjunction elimination and [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

> 7) $P(y') \leftrightarrow y=y'$ --- from 5) and 6) by [Biconditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction)

8) $\forall y' \ (P(y') \leftrightarrow y=y')$ --- from 7) by [Universal genaralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

9) $P(y) \land \forall y' \ (y=y' \leftrightarrow P(y'))$ --- from 2) and 8) by [Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)

> 10) $\exists y \ [P(y) \land \forall y' \ (y=y' \leftrightarrow P(y'))]$ --- from 9) by [Existential introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization).